# ASP.NET: Production always sees GET action

Tags: asp.net, post, get

Going out of my mind here.  I have a simple .aspx page.  The code behind of the load event looks like this:

```
    Private Sub TestPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Write(Request.RequestType)
End Sub
```

When I run it on my development machine it shows "GET", "POST", "PUT" or whatever other action I send.  (I'm using Postman).

But... when I deploy it to my production server it shows "GET" every time no matter what.

What could possibly be the difference?  I can't find anything on this topic anywhere.  Help!

Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending these requests? How have you verified that you're sending a POST request?

Comment: Retrieving page first time only with GET but sending data could be done by GET and Post. You should verify which method you are using to send data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if my description was not clear enough.  I use a program called Postman to initiate the calls.  It has a drop down from which you can choose any of the standard actions (GET, PUT, PUSH, etc)

What is clear is that when it is running on my local computer in the test environment, I see exactly the action that was called from Postman.

BUT... when I deploy this to my production server (on GoDaddy) the exact same calls to the exact same page ALWAYS shows "GET" as the requestType no matter what is sent.